# Can you use an alias on a corporate credit card?

Tags: credit-card

I have never used a corporate credit card, but I imagine they hand you a card with someones else's name on it, and you go to the store and purchase some stuff with it without having to show ID or anything.
I'm wondering how this works. Wondering if you can put basically an alias or an arbitrary name on the corporate card so it isn't tied to any one particular individual.
So maybe it would just say "John Smith", which is a fictitious name, or maybe it wouldn't even need a name at that point.

Answer (score 9):

Your imagination is incorrect. The company should order a card on their account with you as the primary cardholder. The card will show the name of the authorized cardholder, and often the company's name as well. If you try to use a card that has someone *else's* name on it, then you are at the mercy of the retailer as to whether they will accept the card or not.

Note that with most (if not all) American Express corporate cards, YOU are responsible for payment. So if your company goes bust, you are personally responsible for the charges you make.

Comment: Yes. I've had several company credit cards, and in all cases the card had my name on it. One company card I have has the company name on it (in addition to my name). The other doesn't mention the company at all.

Answer (score 3):

A store should not be asking for ID with a credit card.

I gave my minor child a credit card when she was 15, old enough to be out shopping, but not old enough to drive. Credit card, but no other ID.

When I realized I wasn't asked for her social security number, I ordered up a Joe Taxpayer card. I now have a card with my pen name, but of course, no other ID to show if asked.